# PHP - Data-type workaround for $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post, variable-types

I am wondering if there is a way to get a POST array's values to return as something other than type string?

So, for example, if i wanted to:

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
 {
     if (is_X($value)) // X being int or bool or string, etc....
     {
         do something.....
     }
 }
```

I started thinking maybe `settype($var, "type")`
However, I would have to explicitly set the type for every input which seems like an absurd way to go about this.

Comment: You would either have to pass the type or determine it based on some criteria.  Are string 0 and 1 ints or bools?

Comment: That's what you get with languages that are not strongly typed. :)

Comment: No. Everything coming in GET/POST is inherently a string. There is no way around it. You'd have to typecast the strings to something else when you use them. e.g. `$forced_int = (int)$_POST['somekey'];`. As for "absurd": Do you see anywhere in the http spec that allows for such metadata to be put into a query string/form field? `http://example.com/script.php?x:int=42` is not valid, or expected.

Comment: What are the input types you want to do conversions for?  Also why?

Comment: I use $_POST as an example, it could be any array. I could say `foreach ($array as $k => $v)` the result is the same --type string. I am merely wondering if there is a better solution than typecasting @MarcB

Comment: php variables do carry type information. but since anything coming from the outside world DOESN'T care any type information, PHP simply makes it all a string. `$x = 42;` makes $x an integer. `$x = $_GET['field_with_42_for_value']` makes $x a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it can be done with some custom definition of the id names.

Serialization or JSON format would be the best approach. But your question is not specific enough about the context.

```
// Custom definition for fieldnames or keynames
$key_types = array(
    "name" => "string",
    "email" => "string",
    "receive_news" => "bool",
    "age" => "int"
);
// This way you will ALWAYS be sure that type is the same

function castByID($name, $val)
{
    $type = $key_types[$name];
    switch($type)
    {
        default:
        case "string":  $val = (string)$val; break;
        case "bool":  $val = ($val=='1'?true:false); break; // Adapt to your data format
        case "int":  $val = (int)$val; break;
    }
    return $val;
}

if (isset($_POST["user"]))
{
    $data = array();
    foreach ($_POST["user"] as $name => $val) 
        $data[$name] = castByID($name, $val);
}
```

Comment: I would just add that my answer it's your own in some way. But you don't specify if data source comes from server or client. JSON is always the best and more versatile format between server/client. Serialize from PHP is very specific to PHP language.

Answer (score 6):

In short: no. POST data comes through the HTTP protocol, typically x-www-form-urlencoded. This format doesn't specify any types at all, everything is a string. PHP won't and can't magically imbue types on any of these values.

If you want to transport type information, you'll have to use another serialisation format. For example, JSON encode your values on the client and POST the JSON data as request body. JSON is a text format that supports a number of different types.